Latest Hire Date based on table of Start and End Dates
I have a table of job information that looks like this...



Person
Job
StartDate
EndDate
Rate




Jane
Job1
03/01/2024
04/12/2024
1.00


Jane
Job1
04/13/2024
05/20/2024
2.00


Jane
Job1
05/21/2024
07/01/2024
3.00


Jane
Job1
07/02/2024
NULL
4.00


Bobby
Job2
01/01/2024
03/19/2024
1.00


Bobby
Job2
03/20/2024
04/27/2024
2.00


Bobby
Job2
07/03/2024
08/01/2024
2.00


Bobby
Job2
08/02/2024
NULL
3.00




https://dbfiddle.uk/9A1FUvMm

I need a query that will give me the person's latest hire date (if they we re-hired, I want the re-hire date), so the output would be like this...



Person
Latest Hire Date




Jane
03/01/2024


Bobby
07/03/2024



Bobby's date is 07/03/2024 since there is a break between 4/27/2024 and 07/03/2024 aka must have at least 1 day break.
Any ideas on how this can be completed?

What database do you have?

Please explain in more detail how you got the 07/03/2024 for Bobby and 03/01/2024 for Jane?

@nik0x1 Jobs for a person that start the next day after the prior job ended for the same person are effectively the same job.

I'm use a MS SQL 2019 DB.... I'm looking for the latest start dates for continuous employment.... so Jane started on 3/1 and has been employed ever since that date.... Bobby has 7/3 because he worked from 1/1 til 4/27.... got terminated, but then got re-hired on 7/3 so that is his latest hire/re-hire date.  i hope that explains it.

Try this:
WITH Priors AS
(
    select *
       , lag(EndDate) over (partition by Person, Job  order by startdate) PriorEnd
    from JobInfo
)
SELECT person, Max(startdate) as LatestHire
FROM priors 
WHERE priorend < DateAdd(day, -1, StartDate) OR PriorEnd IS NULL
GROUP BY person

See it work here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/gjIWSQuJ


Perfect!  Thank you Joel!  I was trying to do self joins, but couldn't get it right.  I didn't know about LAG, but it works wonderfully.  Thank you again.

You could also do it with a left join and specifying that a row that ended a day prior does not exist.
SELECT Curr.Person, max(Curr.StartDate) as LatestHire
  FROM JobInfo Curr
  Left Join JobInfo Prev  on Prev.Person = Curr.Person
                         and Prev.EndDate = dateadd(day, -1, Curr.StartDate)
 WHERE Prev.Person is null
 GROUP BY Curr.Person

Effectively the same as:
SELECT Curr.Person, max(Curr.StartDate) as LatestHire
  FROM JobInfo Curr
 WHERE not exists (Select 1
                     from JobInfo Prev
                    where Prev.Person = Curr.Person
                      and Prev.EndDate = dateadd(day, -1, Curr.StartDate)
                  )
 GROUP BY Curr.Person;

In my experience, a left join and a check for null runs faster than using a correlated subquery with a not exists.
Try it here: https://dbfiddle.uk/PfkhrYHD

If the Job is part of the key, then: https://dbfiddle.uk/0pfjChTe
